# How to remove lines from text file not starting with certain characters (sed or grep)

Tags: text, sed, grep

How do I delete all lines in a text file which do not start with the characters `#`, `&` or `*`? I'm looking for a solution using `sed` or `grep`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Deleting lines:**

With `grep`

From http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-grep.html :

> The **grep** command selects and prints lines from a file (or a bunch of files) that match a pattern.

I think you can do something like this:

```
grep -v '^[\#\&\*]' yourFile.txt > output.txt
```

---

You can also use `sed` to do the same thing (check http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-sed.html ):

```
sed '^[\#\&\*]/d' yourFile.txt > output.txt
```

It's up to you to decide

---

**Filtering lines:**

My mistake, I understood you wanted to delete the lines. But if you want to "delete" all other lines (or filter the lines starting with the specified characters), then `grep` is the way to go:

```
grep '^[\#\&\*]' yourFile.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: try first with a single expression: `grep -v '^#' yourFile > output`. You may need to escape the characters: `grep -v '^\#' yourFile > output`

Comment: But I need to keep lines begins with & or * or # not delete them. I want to delete all other lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Made the correction. Yes, you're right, one command solves it all. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/^[#&*].*/p' input.txt > output.txt
```

this should work.

```
 sed -ni '/^[#&*].*/p' input.txt
```

this one will edit the input file directly, be careful +

Answer (score 2):

```
egrep '^(&|#|\*)' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Erro that | wasn't excepted.

Comment: In general, it is more efficient to use a character class `[&#*]` than the alternation you show.  If your `egrep` uses a DFA, it probably doesn't matter.